# Div element to fade out and <p> element in DIV to fade in

Tags: html, css

I have image box that on hover, image  goes to 0.5 opacity, and the text inside a DIV have to go from visibility:hidden to go to visibility:visible'. But I am struggling with figuring out how to do it.

```css
    #edno {
 background-image:url(" ../../CONTENT/Images/a.png");
 background-size:100%;
 background-repeat:no-repeat; 
 background-position:center;
 transition: 0.2s linear; 
    }

    #edno:hover {
 background-size:200%;
 background-position:center;
 opacity:0.5; 
    }

    #edno .imee { 
 font-family:futuraat;
 font-size:35px;
 padding-top:204px;
 visibility:hidden;
 color:black; 
    }

    #edno:hover .imee { 
 font-family:futuraat;
 font-size:35px;
 padding-top:204px;
 visibility:visible;
 color:black; 
    }
```

```html
    <a href="../../producti/sekcionni/1/index.html">
          <div class="figure" id="edno">
               <p class="imee">СТЪЛБИЧКА</p>
           </div>
       </a>
```

Everything that happens is that Everything goes on:

```
 opacity:0.5
```

I want the text to pop in when hover the div.

Comment: You can't affect the opacity of a background image.

Comment: @Paulie_D well, in some way you can, by setting the opacity of the whole element, but of course the opacity then applies to all child elements as well.

Comment: I am affecting the the whole div. And it becomes 0.5 opacity. It is happening. The thing I want to do is if it is possible, the <p></p> element to become from hidden to visible without being affected from this 0.5 opacity

Comment: @ВалериК. So if your issue is that you dont want the opacity to affect the inner '<p>', then why haven't you mentioned that in your question? This makes me ask - what is the point of your question, if you're not asking what you need?

Comment: In that case, do not nest your "<p>" element in the div being affected by the opacity. Have it in a different div, place it over the background div and make it work like that. Working on a practical example now.

Answer (score 0):

> I have image box that on hover, image goes to 0.5 opacity, and the text inside a DIV have to go from `visibility:hidden` to go to `visibility:visible` but I am struggling with figuring out how to do it.

Seems to work fine as is? The text **IS** doing that upon hover.

```css
#edno {
 background-image:url("https://placehold.it/300x150");
 background-size:100%;
 background-repeat:no-repeat; 
 background-position:center;
 transition: 0.2s linear; 
    }

    #edno:hover {
 background-size:200%;
 background-position:center;
 opacity:0.5; 
    }

    #edno .imee { 
 font-family:futuraat;
 font-size:35px;
 padding-top:204px;
 visibility:hidden;
 color:black; 
    }

    #edno:hover .imee { 
 font-family:futuraat;
 font-size:35px;
 padding-top:204px;
 visibility:visible;
 color:black; 
    }
```

```html
<a href="../../producti/sekcionni/1/index.html">
          <div class="figure" id="edno">
               <p class="imee">СТЪЛБИЧКА</p>
           </div>
       </a>
```

Comment: It is working, but the <p> element stays at 0.5 opacity. I don't want to be affected by the opacity property.

Comment: @ВалериК. But your question mentioned **nothing** about not wanting the <p> to be affected????

Comment: @ВалериК. You say `from visibility:hidden to go to visibility:visible but I am struggling with figuring out how to do it.` **not** `How can I stop the <p> from being affected by opacity`

Answer (score 0):

Here is some working code, just use a little jQuery to trigger a toggle and VOILA!

CSS:

```
#edno {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: red;
    width:300px;
    height: 200px;
    transition: 0.2s linear;    
    }

    #edno:hover {
    background-size:200%;
    background-position:center;
    opacity:0.5;    
    }

    .imee { 
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    top: -360px;
    font-family:futuraat;
    font-size:35px;
    padding-top:204px;
    display: none;
    color:black;    
    }

    .show
    {
        display: block;
    }
```

HTML:

```
      <a href="#">
          <div class="figure" id="edno"></div>
          <p id="fadeIn" class="imee">СТЪЛБИЧКА</p>
       </a>
```

jQUERY:

```
  $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $("#edno").hover(function()
            {
                $(".imee").toggleClass("show");
            });
        });
```